# Problems with Jquery-Animated Round Divs

Tags: jquery, button, html, jquery-animate, css

SO,

At the risk of getting lost in the sea of "hover animation problems" on the forum, here goes:

I'm developing a series of hover-animated buttons for a landing page. Their hover state is a rounded div:

[image]

And the initial/"mouseoff" state is color-animated text without the div:

[image]

I've got a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/2GE2b/7/) with a script to animate the div's background color so that it fades to brown when the cursor is on it, but I think I'm overlooking something in the syntax as it doesn't seem to be taking effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".corners").hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 'fast');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#8B5E3C"}, 'fast');
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="corners"> 
    <div class="cornertext">Main Site</div> 
</div>
<div class="corners"> 
    <div class="cornertext">Mobile</div> 
</div>
```

Once I've got this property figured out, the goal is to set up a function to change the font color simultaneously, but first I've got to determine what's wrong with the DIV color animation. Help from the talent on SO would be great!

-Marca    ​

Comment: As you may not have seen my answer, as I deleted it(due to wrong information), I have since re-posted it with the correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the ui library.  I have a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2GE2b/10/).  Make sure you include [the library](http://jqueryui.com/) after your inclusion of jquery.

Also see [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) for the specifics regarding the expansion of `.animate()`

Comment: Ahah thanks Daedalus! I'd completely overlooked color transitions as a UI thing. One question based on your JSfiddle though - I've adjusted it so the DIV appears on hover, yet my initial state still shows the div (as though the mouseoff state doesn't kick in until after the cursor has hovered over it). Do I need to change the JS for the function to solve this? JSfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/XSc7A/1/

Comment: @Marcatectura Not the js actually, but the css.  For your `.corner` class, change `background:` to `#fff`, so the initial rendering is as you want it to be.

Comment: Daedalus, done! Thanks so much. I do have a follow-up question - I've tried to add a font-color animation. However, I seem to be screwing that up too. I'm really showing my ignorance of Jquery, but if you're interested, the JSfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/8vne5/7/

Comment: @Marcatectura Your current problem is your [object is structured wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/8vne5/8/), the members of an object are separated by commas, not semi-colons.